# Home page is not displaying as the first term in google search

Tags: web

We have enable our website in Google Analytics and we have also used meta tags inside our jsp file.

Our website home page is not showing as first search term in Google and some sub pages are showed.

How can we get our homepage to show instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sitemap.

You can find more info here: [Sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

In a sitemap, you can set the priority of each page, so your homepage will appear above your other pages.

Keep in mind, though, you also have to have *actual, relevant content* on your homepage for it to show above others.

Answer (score 0):

Their can multiple reasons. As you are saying, only homepage isn't showing. Then the mostly likely issue comes out is that it isn't indexed.

Another reason may be your is password-protected

OR

Your page has "no index" tags